# Display a local PDF file with CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm trying to display a local pdf file using a custom `LocalSchemeHandler` which reads a memory stream from the file.

The file exists and the memory stream is being read properly. But there is nothing being displayed in the browser window. Displaying the same file via *file scheme* works.

ResourceHandler:

```
public class LocalSchemeHandler : ResourceHandler
{
    public override bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(request.Url);
        var file = uri.AbsolutePath;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (callback)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(file))
                {
                    callback.Cancel();
                    return;
                }

                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

                var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    callback.Cancel();
                }
                else
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    ResponseLength = stream.Length;

                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    MimeType = GetMimeType(fileExtension);
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    Stream = stream;

                    callback.Continue();
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

ISchemeHandlerFactory:

```
public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    public const string SchemeName = "local";

    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        return new LocalSchemeHandler();
    }
}
```

Settings:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
{
    SchemeName = CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
    SchemeHandlerFactory = new CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory()
});
// Increase the log severity so CEF outputs detailed information, useful for debugging
settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Default;
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

**EDIT**
Trying to display the PDF file via ResourceHandler.FromFilePath also doesn't work (nothing is displayed).

```
public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    public const string SchemeName = "local";

    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(request.Url);
        var file = uri.AbsolutePath;

        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file);
        var mimeType = ResourceHandler.GetMimeType(fileExtension);
        return ResourceHandler.FromFilePath(file, mimeType);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

After setting LogSeverity to Default the log says: `[0524/150955.108:INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Refused to load plugin data from 'local://c/Users/abidh/Desktop/pdf.pdf' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src * blob: externalfile: file: filesystem: data:".`

Comment: What is MimeType set to?

Comment: application/pdf

Comment: Try the built in implementation https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/63/CefSharp.Example/CefSharpSchemeHandlerFactory.cs#L77

Comment: ResourceHandler.FromFilePath doesn't work either (see edit)

Comment: What does the log file say? By default it's debug.log

Comment: That's it!? See edits ... But what can I do about it?

Comment: Did you Google the error? My suggestion is to either register your scheme handler to use http as a scheme name or disable CSP by setting http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefCustomScheme_IsCSPBypassing.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot. Disabling CSP did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't find a solution using google. Thanks to [amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583726/amaitland), using the `IsCSPBypassing` property solved the problem:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
{
    SchemeName = CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
    SchemeHandlerFactory = new CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory(),
    IsCSPBypassing = true
});
settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Error;
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the PDF file path to ChromiumWebBrowser.Address as format like file:///C:/Users/xxx/yyy.pdf, the CEFSharp will render PDF just like Chrome browser.

Comment: .Address property is readonly and cannot be set

Comment: This worked for me. I have the Address bound to a string property and it displays the pdf.